# How to identify values changed in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here i have one doubt this would be very dumb question but am struggling with this am having one login activity and list activity in login activity it will communicate with remote server and will get json response from server for example will get userid which i'l save it in sharedpreference and will pass that value in listactivity for detail list till this is everything is fine but my doubt is when new user login i need to send null  to url in listactivity  from next time il get time from response based on that response will be altered for that how can i check the value in sharedprefrence whether its a first time or already logged in !!

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more entry in shared preference with any key.
On onCreate of your MainActivity check that key, if its false, then update it to true.

So, that way, if you get false then its your first time and if you get true, then its logged in.

Please follow steps in below link

[Detect First Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765700/detect-first-run)

Comment: can you shared some snippet

Comment: @YogeshLegendkiller: Why don't you try the suggest approach, rather than asking for code straight away?